# How do I add class using jquery/javascript to different elements depending on what day is it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

For example I have 4 div's. And each div has specific day/days, when a class has to be added to it, like so:

```
<div class="on-17 on-18"></div>
<div class="on-20"></div>
<div class="on-21"></div>
<div class="on-22"></div>
```

And I want to add class active on first div, if today is 17th or 18th of current month. Any ideas? Im not saying I need to extract "on-17" to get number 17, it can be manual method, just to check for certain 'on-#'s, in this case 17,18,20,21,22.

For example, if today was 2015-03-17th, it would trigger to add acive class on `<div class="on-17 on-18"></div>` -> `<div class="on-17 on-18 active"></div>`

Comment: a little bit more explanation is required to make the question clearer than this mud. thanks

Comment: This question spans almost a whole project. ;) You've got a couple of distinct problems: 1. Get which day it is. 2. Compare that value to a predefined value 3. Apply a class to an element. Each of these shouldn't be that hard, so I'd advise you to tackle them one at a time and ask specific questions (including your attempts) if you don't succeed.

Comment: added example for my problem. I dont know how to check what day is it with jquery today.

Comment: well today is the 3th of March which is nowhere in your `<divs>` so what to do then?

Comment: then do nothing at all.  Im just interesting in adding active class on elements, where on-day class is present.

Comment: silly concept, set the content at server based on date instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need jQuery to check what date it is. You can use plain Javascript for that.

```
var today = new Date();

if(today.getDate() === 17) {
  $('.on-17').addClass('active');
}
```

A more dynamic implementation that always adds class `active` to the current day's div:

```
var today = new Date();
var dayOfMonth = today.getDate();

$('on-' + dayOfMonth).addClass('active');
```

If you have different numbered classes for each day (say you want every day to have a different color):

```
var today = new Date();
var dayOfMonth = today.getDate();

$('on-' + dayOfMonth).addClass('active-' + dayOfMonth); //Will add the class active-17 on the 17th day of each month, for example
```

Comment: Perfect, that all I needed. As simple as that.